# Can I use ActiveJob with an Amazon SWF backend?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf, ruby-on-rails-4.2, rails-activejob

There's all kinds of documentation out there about the new ActiveJob framework included in Rails 4.2. But there is no documentation about how to actually write a backend for it. Or in general, what the framework expects from a backend.

I was wondering if ActiveJob was able to work against Amazon SWF as a backend? From an architecture standpoint, are there obstacles? Things I should consider?

Comment: I never used Amazon SWF but an adapter for it shouldn't be too complicated. Take a look at host other adapters are implemented https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activejob/lib/active_job/queue_adapters